# Does Titanium Rifling negate the downsides of Super Heavy Compound?

Tags: synthetik

The effects of the Super Heavy Compound weapon mod increase base damage, but reduce movement speed and add damage drop off over distance. The Titanium Rifling Weapon mod eliminates damage drop off over distance or adds damage over distance to weapons without any damage drop off. Does one of these effects have a stronger impact than the other? Does one negate the other? Does the order that they are applied change anything?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the opportunity to test it in game, and it looks as if it does not.
The order I applied was Rifling, then Super Heavy.

Comment: Now all we need to do is test it in the reverse order and we'll have it figured out.